# How can you fly a plane without arms?

Tags: pilots

I hear about [Jessica Cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Cox); born without arms, she is the world's first licensed armless pilot.

How can you pilot a plane without arms? How are the controls modified in order to let her fly?

Anyway: great respect for this woman. Absolutely.

Comment: I read the title: I thought this was going to be about weapons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jessica Cox explains it herself in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2IqpPSF9-U

She's using her legs in place of hands (I.e, using her feet to manipulate the controls, throttle etc) and she specifically flies an Ercoupe which has no rudder pedals.